# NSTask: program launching another program, how to do?

Tags: cocoa, path, terminal, sh, nstask

I want to do with an `NSTask` what I am able to do in the terminal via

```
$ myprogram myfile.ext
```

I know that `myprogram` (I don't have any control on this program) launches another program `myauxprogram`. Furthermore, the path to `myprogram` is `path1` and the path to `myprogram` is `path2`.

If I do

```
 NSTask * myTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];

 NSArray * arguments = @[@"myfile.ext"] ;

 [myTask setCurrentDirectoryPath:[URLOfTheFolder path]];
 [myTask setLaunchPath:@"/path1/myprogram"];
 [myTask setArguments:arguments];

 [myTask launch] ;
```

I get the following error `sh: myauxprogam: command not found`

If I create a symbol link in `path1` to `myauxprogram`, the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:

You need to `[myTask setEnvironment:...]` so that the task knows which are the environment variables (`PATH`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mostly have the idea, you're just missing a few key elements. `NSTask` should have a defined LaunchPath, such as `/usr/bin/sh`, `/usr/bin`, etc. from there depending on the type of path you're requiring you set up your arguments and options.

```
NSTask *auxTask;
NSTask *auxPath = @"./path1/myprogram";        // period might be needed
NSTask *auxArgs = @"myfile.ext";

auxTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[auxTask setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/sh"];         // use shell

[auxTask setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             @"-c",             // -c will exec as shell cmd
                             auxPath,
                             auxArgs,
                             nil]];

    // using `try` is optional

    @try
    {
        [auxTask launch];
    }
    @catch(id exc)
    {
        auxTaskSuccess = NO;
    }
    [auxTask release];

return;
```

No idea if this works, but this is the way you would likely set things up. If you run into issues with errors or the `NSTask` failing you can set up an `NSLog` with the auxTask `NSArray` to see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: So you want to apply something there to this I presume? You'd have to show me which one worked and then we can fix the code above.